# GLSL log returning an undefined result

Tags: c++, glsl, vulkan

I'm trying to draw the mandelbrot set. I've created the algorithm on the CPU, but now I want to reproduce it on the GPU, but the code behaves differently.

In the CPU program, at one point, I take the std::abs(z), where z is a complex number, and write the value in the green channel on the screen.

On the GPU, I take the same z and call the following function (Vulkan, GLSL):

```
double module(dvec2 z) {
    return sqrt(z.x * z.x + z.y * z.y);
}

double color(z) {
    return module(z);
}
```

When I write color(z) into the green channel, I get the same exact picture as I get for the CPU program, so the code works exactly the same, at least up to that point.

Next, I changed the CPU code to instead take `std::log(std::abs(z)) / 20` and put that in the green channel. This is the image I get (nubmers that are in the mandelbrot set are coloured white):
[image]

You can see that the green is never clipped, so the result for the each pixel is somewhere in the range (0, 1).

I then changed the GPU code to this:

```
double module(dvec2 z) {
    return sqrt(z.x * z.x + z.y * z.y);
}

double color(z) {
    return log(module(z));
}
```

I wrote `color(z) / 20` into the green channel. This is the resulting image:
[image]

As you can see, the value of `color(z) / 20` must be <=0. I tried changing the `color` function to this:

```
double color(z) {
    return -log(module(z));
}
```

To see if the value was 0 or negative. I still got the same image, so the value must be 0. To confirm this I change the code again, now to this:

```
double color(z) {
    return log(module(z)) + 0.5;
}
```

and wrote `color(z)` to the green channel (dropping the division by 20). I expected the result to be a medium green colour.

To my surprise, the image did not change, the pixels were still pitch black.

Perplexed, I reverted the change to the original:

```
double color(z) {
    return log(module(z));
}
```

but, I wrote `color(z) + 0.5` into the green channel and I got this:
[image]

To summarize, it seems that `log(module(z))` is returning some undefined value. If you negate it or try to add anything to it, it remains undefined. When this value is return from a function that has a `double` as the return type, the value returned is 0, which can now be added to.

Why does this happen? The function `module(z)` is guaranteed to return a positive number so the log function should return a valid result. The definitions of both `std::log` and `GLSL log` are the natural logarithm of the argument, so the value should be exactly the same (ignoring the precision error).

How do I make `GLSL log` behave properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that GPU doesn't really like when you ask it to calculate a log of a very large number. From what I gather, log (actually ln) is implemented as the taylor series. This is unfortunate because it contains polynomials to the n-th power for n members.

However, if you have a number represented as `x = mantissa * 2^exp`, you can get `ln(x)` from the following formula:

```
ln(x) = exp * ln(2) + ln(mantissa)
```

Whatever x is, mantissa should be significantly smaller. Here's a function for the fragment shader:

```
float ln(float z) {
    int integerValue = floatBitsToInt(z);
    int exp = ((integerValue >> mantissaBits) & (1 << expBits) - 1)
              - ((1 << (expBits - 1)) - 1);

    integerValue |= ((1 << expBits) - 1) << mantissaBits;
    integerValue &= ~(1 << (mantissaBits + expBits - 1));

    return exp * log2 + log(intBitsToFloat(integerValue));
}
```

Note that in GLSL this trick only works with floats - there is not 64bit integral type and thus not doubleBitsToLong or vice versa.